# Difference between Membership Provider in ASP.NET Webforms and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-membership, webforms, membership-provider

Is there a difference in the working between the Membership Provider of Webforms and Membership Provider of MVC 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

- The membership provider is part of the `System.Web.Security` namespace
- Webforms is the `System.Web.UI` namespace
- MVC is the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace

Therefore, there are no dependencies.  In other words, you'll be making the same membership calls with the same membership objects in an MVC application as you would in a WebForms application.

Answer (score 1):

No, MVC is just a design pattern that Microsoft has utilized. So, you can use membership in all ASP.Net projects.

This is evident even in the namespace:
System.**Web**.Security